# Css animation on mobile move page up and text inside <p> tag doesn't break line instead enlarge the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have 2 problems with my code right now:

1) I'm actually using an animation for some divs. The animation is perfect on desktop, but when used on mobile the page moves up a bit.

2) I'm using AJAX to retrieve some information from my DB, the only problem is the when there is too much text inside the

the text doesn't break and continue in a new row, instead it enlarge the page

I've created a JSFiddle with all the code i'm using.

For the first problem i can't recreate the problem using JSFiddle, but the code is the same as my website and the error occurs, maybe you can find it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Cerca il personal trainer perfetto per te">
    <meta name="author" content="Davide">
    <title>Find your PT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
  </head>

  <body id="page-top">
    <section class="page-section pb-5 text-center text-white" id="services">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="slideInRight">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Sei in cerca di un PT?</h1>
          <p class="font-weight-light">Potrai entrare in contatto con il personal trainer perfetto per te. Inizia subito il tuo percorso verso il corpo dei tuoi sogni</p>
          <button id="signInAsUser" type="button" class="btn btn-dark loginService">Iscriviti come cliente</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid" id="slideInLeft">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Sei un PT in cerca di clienti?</h1>
          <p class="font-weight-light">Potrai offrire le tue conoscenze tecniche agli utenti, aiutandoli a raggiungere i propri obiettivi</p>
          <button id="signInAsPt" type="button" class="btn btn-danger loginService">Iscriviti come PT</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="reviews" class="border-bottom">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><hr></div>
        <div class="col-auto"><h3>Recensioni</h3></div>
        <div class="col"><hr></div>
      </div>
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner h-100" id="reviewList">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <p class="text-danger"><strong><em> PT: <a href="#" class="linkToPt"  data-id="1">Fanto</a></em></strong></p>
    <h5>askldnaksdn laskndlasn dlaknslkndalksndlasnl k</h5>
    <p>asldknasldknalksdnkalsndklasndlansdklansldknaklsdnalksdnklanlansldkansldknaklsndkalsndlkdnasnkldasnklasdnkldnklaasdnklasdnklnklasdasdnklasdnklasdnklasdnklnklasdasdnklasdnkllnd</p>
    <p>4</p>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="page-section p-5" id="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
            <h2 class="font-weight-bold">Hai bisogno di aiuto?</h2>
            <p class="font-weight-lighter">Hai problemi a visualizzare il sito web? Non riesci a metterti in contatto con nessun Personal Trainer?
              Inviaci un email e ti risponderemo il prima possibile!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if(window.scrollTo) window.scrollTo(0,0);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function() {
        var top_of_element = $("#slideInRight").offset().top;
        var bottom_of_element = $("#slideInRight").offset().top + $("#slideInRight").outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
        var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > ($( window ).height() - $(".navbar").height() * 2));
        if ((bottom_of_screen > top_of_element) && (top_of_screen < bottom_of_element)) {
            if ($("#slideInRight").hasClass("toLeft")) {} else {
                $("#slideInRight").addClass("toLeft");
            }
            if ($("#slideInLeft").hasClass("toRight")) {} else {
                $("#slideInLeft").addClass("toRight");
            }
        }

        $('.hideme').each(function (i) {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 500);
            }
        });
    });
});


$('#reviewList').on('click', '.linkToPt', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("ptId", $(this).data("id"));
    window.location.href = location.origin + "/../php/view/profile.html";
});

$('#signInAsPt').click(function () {
    window.location.href = location.origin + "/php/view/loginSignup.html?checked=1";
});

$('#signInAsUser').click(function () {
    window.location.href = location.origin + "/php/view/loginSignup.html?checked=0";
});
```

```
/* General */
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* Navbar */
.navbar-default{
    transition:100ms ease;
    background: #0000003b;
}
.navbar-default.scrolled{
    background:#000;
}


/* Login Menu Animation*/
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .animate {
        animation-duration: 0.3s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
        animation-fill-mode: both;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0rem);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    0% {
        transform: translateY(1rem);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(1rem);
    }
}

.slideIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-name: slideIn;
}


/* Full Screen Image */
.masthead {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(105,105,105,.8) 0,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%),url(../img/bg-masthead.jpg) !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* Reviews */
.carousel{
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 250px;
}

.carousel-inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption{
    color: black !important;
    top: 50%;
}

.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev{
    color:black !important;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    outline: black;
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: none;
}

.carousel-control-next-icon:after
{
    content: '>';
    font-size: 55px;
    color: red;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon:after {
    content: '<';
    font-size: 55px;
    color: red;
}


/* Animation */
.hideme{
    opacity:0;
}


/* Diagonal Divs + animation*/
.container-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8rem 0;
}

.toLeft {
    background: #b31c2a;
    transform: skewY(-2deg);
    animation: enterFromRight 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.toLeft .container {
    transform: skewY(2deg);
}

.toRight {
    background: black;
    transform: skewY(2deg);
    animation: enterFromLeft 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.toRight .container {
    transform: skewY(-2deg);
}

@keyframes enterFromLeft {
    from {
        margin-left: -90%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes enterFromRight {
    from {
        margin-left: 90%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the link: [JSfiddle]: https://jsfiddle.net/cha50tej/2/

Answer (score 1):

For the text problem, try adding `word-break: break-all` for that `p` tag. That should cause the text to wrap.

Comment: Good to hear. Cheers!